# Push JSON data to Jquery Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, type-conversion

I try to push some data, `val.related` and `val.keywords` to an array `keywords`. But the Array's still empty after that. Any ideas ?

```
//get data.
var getProjectsApi = function() {

    //keywords.
    var keywords = [];

    //get data via json.
    $.getJSON('projects/api', function(data) {

        //loop over keywords.
        $.each(data.keywords, function(i, val) {

            //push content to keywords-array.
            keywords.push('<li data-related="' + val.related + '">' + val.keyword + '</li>');   
        });

        console.log( keywords );
    });

    //return the array.
    return keywords;
}
```

Comment: check server side if it really is returg values

Comment: Yes it does return those values.

Comment: I recommedn that you always check returned data before using it: `if (typeof data != 'undefined')`. Same for `data.keywords`.

Comment: @GytisŠk good point, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making an async ajax call that's why keywords is not filled. You need to wait till the array is filled with value. So, You have make your ajax call as sync. To do this you can use ajaxSetup method before calling getJson method.

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

Comment: Its not returning null. I receive the data. Its only when im pushing it the array doesnt get filled up.

Comment: ok. It did not work on my first attempt but now it does with your solution. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't mean that data is coming null, I have edited my post its clear now. I am just saying, after making ajax call it goes to next line.